# notepad++ regular expression how to replace nth occurance of the string ", " with comma-newline

Tags: regex

I have been trying to understand regular expressions so I can find every nth occurance of `,` (comma-space)  with `,\r\n` (comma-carriage return) to clarify: i want to replace n+1 occurances of the string and replace it with `,\r\n` (comma-carriage return). there must be a comma at the end of the line.

the original data will looks like

```
"aa", "aah", "aal", "aalii", "aardvark", "aardvarks", "aardwolf", "aardwolves", "aargh", "aarrghh", "aasvogel", "aasvogels", "ab", "aba", "abaca", "abacas"
```

the proceeding / character marks the beginning and end of the regex

the expression (, ) matches correctly. ive tried /(, ).{n}/ and /(, ){n}/ and no luck. 
my desired output is something like this

```
"aa", "aah", "aal", "aalii",
"aardvark", "aardvarks", "aardwolf", "aardwolves",
"aarrghh", "aasvogel", "aasvogels", "ab",
"aba", "abaca", "abacas", "abaci",
```

in this case ive replaced every 5th occurance of (, ) with a newline. it would be great if the regex could be easily modified to accept nth occurances. my total dataset is in the 49,000 word range

Comment: Please post a clear sample of the **input** and desired **output**

Answer (score 1):

The `(...){n}` doesn't work like that.  If you match `defabcdefdefghidef` against `{def){2}` then it will match the defdef in the middle but the capture group is the second instance of def in that match - the first def in the match is lost and doesn't capture at all.  So saying `(, ){3}` will match `, , ,` and that doesn't exist in your data.  You could do `("[^"]+", ){3}` and that will match `"abc", "def", "ghi",` but you can't replace it with `\1\r\n` because the capture group is only `"ghi",` so the result would be that `"abc", "def",` gets deleted.

You need to NOT use `{n}` at all.  Instead of `("[^"]+", ){3}` use `("[^"]+", "[^"]+", "[^"]+", )` and replace it with `\1\r\n`

Online example:
https://www.myregextester.com/?r=3d00df0a

Answer (score 0):

**Find what**: `,\s`
**Replace with**: `\r\n`

---

Output:

```
"aa"
"aah"
"aal"
"aalii"
...etc
```

---

[image]

---

[Regex Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/myRcj9/1)